# Kotlin Function to return boolean between date/hour range (Android)

Tags: android, date, datetime, kotlin

I'm searching for an example with a function comparing a date and hours range for example in a restaurant for opening hours , the function return true if I put in parameters Sunday - Tuesday from 10:00 AM - 23:00 PM, What is the best way to do it? there is multiples date instances in Java/Kotlin I'm a little bit confused...

Comment: @Raman your answer was not complete, it didn't help me. now I have more questions about my problem...

Answer (score 3):

The Kotlin-idiomatic way to do this would be to define your restaurant opening hours as a `ClosedRange<T>` (where `T` is some kind of date/time value, see further discussion below), and then use the `in` operator to determine if your given time falls within that range. See [Ranges and Progressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html) in the Kotlin documentation.

To define the range you use the [`rangeTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/range-to.html) function (or [`..`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#arithmetic) operator) e.g.:

```
val range = start..end
```

You can then use the [`contains`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-closed-range/contains.html) function (or [`in`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#in) operator) e.g.

```
anInstant in range
```

to determine if the given instant `anInstant` falls into the range or not.

As to the actual representation of the date/time values, it depends on your target platforms. If you are targeting JVM or Android, you can use any of the classes in `java.time`. For example, you can use a zone-aware date representation like `ZonedDateTime`, or one that ignores zones all-together like `LocalDateTime`, or one that represents a particular `Instant` in time regardless of zone, depending on your application's business rules for handling time zones.

If you are targeting multi-platform (e.g. native or JavaScript), then you'll probably want to look into a cross-platform library with date/time representations, like [kotlinx-datetime](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you no longer looking for an answer but this is the answer anyway

```
fun isNowInRange(start: LocalTime, stop: LocalTime, now: LocalTime): Boolean{
        return ( ! now.isBefore( start ) ) && ! now.isAfter( stop )
    }
```

and this is how to use it

```
isNowInRange(LocalTime.of(9, 0), LocalTime.of(23, 0) // opne

!isNowInRange(LocalTime.of(9, 0), LocalTime.of(23, 0) // closed
```

and if there is any restaurant that's open after 24 midnight you can write this

```
if (isNowInRange(LocalTime.of(9, 0), LocalTime.of(23, 0) && isNowInRange(LocalTime.of(0, 0), LocalTime.of(4, 0)){

// restaurant is open from 9am till 4am 
// do stuff here

}else{

// restaurant closed from 4am till 9am
// do stuff here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun checkIfInRangeOfHours(startHour: String, endHour: String): Boolean {
    val currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().time
    val currentDate = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH).format(currentTime)
    val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm", Locale.ENGLISH)
    val startDate: Date? = simpleDateFormat.parse("$currentDate $startHour")
    val endDate: Date? = simpleDateFormat.parse("$currentDate $endHour")
    return Date().after(startDate) && Date().before(endDate)
}
```

Comment: Please, add some information, avoid to just post code without explanations